# PHP alternative to mysql_data_seek for ODBC

Tags: php, db2, odbc

I am converting a PHP-mySQL application to a PHP-ODBC application. ie getting the database migrated from mysql to DB2.

While using mysql i used `mysql_data_seek` function so as to reset the recordset pointer, but this does not work for ODBC connection. I tried and checked `odbc_fetch_row($recordset,0)` for resetting the recordset, but this does not work. Does anyone know how to reset the recordset via ODBC connection?

Comment: What's your cursor type at `odbc_connect()`?

Comment: cursor type is `SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC`

Comment: In case we are not using the cursor type as `SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC` (not supported) What should be the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-row.php), you need to pass `1` as the second parameter instead of `0`.

> To step through the result more than once, you can call
>   odbc_fetch_row() with row_number 1, and then continue doing
>   odbc_fetch_row() without row_number to review the result.

However, note that if your driver doesn't support this method, there may not be a way to accomplish this task:

> If a driver doesn't support fetching rows by number,
>   the row_number parameter is ignored.